# How is a Link/URL forwarded to another application?

Tags: linux, parameter-passing, handler, forwarding, thunderbird

i tried to find out, how for example Thunderbird forwards the link i'm clicking on, to the specified application (content type setting).

I want to write my own link handler. At the moment my handler starts but i have no clue how to access the link.

Can you help me?

Comment: Start research with [xdg-open](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open), it opens the app

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what i'm searching for. Thunderbird has it's own preferred application settings. I want to know, how Thunderbird passes the link to the specified application. This is independent from my system-wide settings.

Comment: I missed the forest for the trees ...

The link is forwarded as an argument. Sorry for the disturbance!